# Webcam doesn't work on Raspberry Pi VIDIOC-QUERYMENU: Invalid Argument

Tags: raspbian, python, webcam, opencv, image

So I wrote an image processing program in Python on my windows computer and it works fine there, but when I try to run it on the Raspberry Pi I get `VIDIOC-QUERYMENU: Invalid Argument` a bunch of times.

I have a Logitech c920 which is a officially compatible camera with raspberry pi.  I'm using python, numpy and opencv2.